# ASP.NET MVC Catch All Parameter and creating a sitemap over that

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, mvcsitemapprovider

In ASP.NET MVC, I have a defined catch-all route as below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "TagsRoute",
    "tags/{*tags}",
    new { controller = "home", action = "tags"}
);
```

Inside the controller, I am querying the products which has entered `{tags}` as below:

```
public ViewResult(string[] tags) { 

    var model = _repo.Get(tags);

    return View(model);
}
```

What I am struggling with is how to create a sitemap over this with [MVCSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) `DynamicNodeProviderBase` class.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sitemap node:

`<mvcSiteMapNode title="Tags" action="Tags" controller="Home" dynamicNodeProvider="Your.Namespace.TagsDynamicNodeProvider, YourAssemblyName" />`

The provider itself would be something along these lines:

```
public class TagsDynamicNodeProvider
    : DynamicNodeProviderBase
{
    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection()
    {
        DynamicNode node = new DynamicNode();
        node.Title = "Some title";
        node.RouteValues.Add("tags", new string[]{"tag1", "tag2"});

        yield return node; 
    }

    public override CacheDescription GetCacheDescription()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! Something I am trying to achieve is a little different. I would like to have a sitemap breadcrumbs like `tags > tag1 > tag2 > tag3`. Also, this dynamic node generates only one sitemap `loc` entry as `http://localhost:28874/tags/System.String%5B%5D`. I guess it is not possible to do this with OOB features.

Comment: In that case you can play around with the node's .Key and .ParentKey properties and build the hierarchy yourself.

Comment: Hmm, I have nearly 50 tags and idea of iterating through all the options, which those 50 tags hold, sounds  like a performance burden at the start-up:s I should probably design that controller action differently, maybe forcing a max tag length of 5. Thanks a lot!